# Looking for a simple private gallery [PHP]

Tags: php, gallery, private

I am planning to create myself a photo storing solution - like dropbox, just in my own server and only with photos.
I was thinking of only one public page - login form. So when you enter www.example.com > you end up with a login form > after login you see your albums and you can easily create new ones/upload photos, bulk download and etc.
The system has to be super easy to use (senior citizen will be using it), should be compatible with mobile phones and all photos should be absolutely private!

I have searched online, but most of the systems are overcrowded with unnecessary tools that make the system complicated and orientated more to public galleries.

Any ideas of similar systems already created that I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options here, personally I would just build this as that way you are **getting exactly what you want**.

However, not everyone has the time or patience I have. So as an alternative :

[OwnCloud](http://owncloud.org/) is the best option here **in my opinion** as I have installed and used this before. It is very user friendly and simple to install.

OR I would suggest investigating these : [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/owncloud/)